# What is the significance of "loop()" method in Actors body - GPars

Tags: groovy, actor, gpars

In Actors body we need to write react() method inside loop() method. I want to know how this loop method is different from "for" or "while" loop?

GPars documentation says "loop() cooperates with nested react() blocks and will ensure looping across subsequent message retrievals." I do not exactly understand this. As per my understanding whatever closure we supply to loop method, that will be executed again and again for infinite number of times. So what is all about coordinating with nested react() blocks?

Answer (score 4):

I believe there is a good explanation in this [DrDobbs article from last year](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/229402193) (bottom of page 1 and start of page 2)

You can basically do this sort of thing to model continuations (from the bottom of page 1):

```
def actor = actor {
    loop {
        log 'Waiting for a gift'
        react {gift ->
            if (myWife.likes gift) reply 'Thank you!'
            else {
                reply 'Try again, please'
                react {anotherGift ->
                    if (myChildren.like gift) reply 'Thank you!'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a way that allows the Actor to be detached from the current thread (described at the start of Page 2 of that article).

Answer (score 2):

A minor addition to what Tim has said - for (or while) loops will not work as expected inside actor's body, since they do not know about the react's continuations. Simply put, loop() is the only way to do iterations across subsequent message retrievals (reacts) in actor's body.